# Is it possible to use AWS Lambda to process an HTTP response without making the corresponding HTTP request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I have to make an HTTP request that takes a long time to receive a response.  I don't want AWS Lambda to make this request as I will be charged for the time it is waiting for the response.  Is there any way to use AWS Lambda to handle the response without being charged while waiting?

Comment: so you just want to make an HTTP call and not wait for the API call's response correct?

Comment: I want my lambda function to process the response.  I don't care how the HTTP request is made as long as lambda isn't running between the response and request.

Comment: I think a better approach would be if the source can publish it's response to an SQS/S3/Dynamodb, which could trigger your function for further processing

Comment: I don't have control over the HTTP server.

Comment: Does it have an endpoint that you could call later? like after some time after invoking it?

Comment: to retrieve the result?  no, unfortunately not.

Comment: Something will have to wait for the response. No way around that. What can you live with? One source makes the request, waits for the response, then passes it to your lambda function. Also, what's a long time? 10 seconds? 10 minutes?

Comment: @Chris It's a long-polling endpoint, so it's intended that I send a request and wait for a response.  Could be immediate, could be a day.  Is there any way to have API Gateway make the request and send the response (even if it's a read timeout) to lambda?

Comment: Instead of connecting and waiting for a response, why not just hit the endpoint often. You could use a CloudWatch Rule to trigger your lambda every X minutes. Lambda hits the endpoint and times out after 5 - 10 seconds. I'm assuming the endpoint will deliver once and you won't miss. The question is how often do you need to hit it at that point.

Comment: @Chris thanks, i will give that a try.  a 1-second try every 5-minutes should be ok for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, I would recommend hitting the long poll endpoint often as opposed to staying connected for long periods of time. You can use a CloudWatch Rule to trigger the lambda function every 5 minutes (or whatever interval you choose). You can give the Lambda a short timeout, say 5-10 seconds, which should prevent it from running for too long. I'm assuming the long poll endpoint will guarantee delivery at least once.

Here is some CloudFormation YAML to get you started on the setup. Far from complete, but should get you on the right track.

```
Description: Automatically hit long poll endpoint
Resources:

  #################################################
  # IAM Role for Lambda
  #################################################
  ROLELAMBDADEFAULT:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: your-lambda-default
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - edgelambda.amazonaws.com
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
      Policies: []


  #################################################
  # Lambda function
  #################################################
  LFUNC:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: bucket-with-code
        S3Key: code.zip
      Description: Some function name
      FunctionName: my-function-name
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 256
      Role: !GetAtt ROLELAMBDADEFAULT.Arn
      #choose your runtime here
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Timeout: 6

  #################################################
  # Rule to trigger the lambda
  #################################################
  RULE1:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: custom-trigger
      Description: Trigger my lambda
      ScheduleExpression: rate(5 minutes)
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt LFUNC.Arn
          Id: uniqueid1
```

Comment: i was going to set a read timeout within my lambda function, so it's not affected by cold start or connection times.  thanks.